What are the reasons to use a downward vertical stabilizer?
Came across this AGM-129_ACM missile and noticed its downward vertical stabilizer and then I also recalled seeing other aircraft (just can't recall which one) with downward vertical stabilizer as well.
What are the reasons to use this unconventional design on an aircraft and/or what would be the reasons this manufacturer chose this design?

source

It's written in the Wikipedia entry: "The jet engine exhaust was shielded by the tail and cooled by a diffuser to reduce the infrared signature of the missile"

At least in the F-16, is has both an upward-facing vertical stabilizer, and a smaller downward facing one. When at high angles of attack, the flow over the upward facing one can become separated, so a stabilizer on the bottom was needed.

If it's air launched a vertical fin could interfere with the rack it mounts to...

Tail is easier to reach, for short maintenance staff ?

@MichaelHall if it's air launched it could half roll short after launch and proceed its task with that yaw stabilizer pointing wherever it points

@user721108, Sure, and then somebody asks "why does it do a half roll after launch instead of just flying with the stabilizer pointing down?"

The question must rather be "why are vertical stablizers usually facing upward?", with a rather obvious answer ;-).

The answer provided by user71659 is very good and answers the radar-detection aspects.
One of your big questions, however, is why this unconventional design?  The answer is that most aircraft are designed to safely land on a flat surface.  Downward vertical stabilizers generally interfere with landing gear.  Missiles, on the other hand, are designed to never return to base (but occasionally do so when they malfunction or are improperly programmed).  Because they don't have to be concerned about landing, their designs do not need to adhere to typical aircraft conventions that require landing accommodations.
Given that the AGM-129 ACM was used to deploy nuclear warheads, landing was not a concern.
In some cases, as Michael Hall alluded to in the comments, an upward vertical stabilizer could interfere with mounting hardware or launch aircraft flight surfaces.  The B-52H was always used as the launch aircraft for the AGM-129 ACM, but the flight surfaces of the AGM-129 ACM would be retracted pre-flight to prevent interference with the mounts and flight surfaces of the Stratofortress.
A typical 3-cluster mount configuration looked like this (thanks to Sophit for providing the image link):

image source: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AGM-129A_-_2006_0306_b52_2lg.jpg

Sorry but this answer isn't that correct: When they are stored or attached to the launcher airplane (B-52 for example), wing and empennage are normally folded no matter where they are placed, as it's just the case for the AGM-129 in the question. The correct answer is therefore the one of @user71659

@sophit Thanks. For some reason, I thought only the lateral stabilizers were retracted until deployment, not the vertical one.  Thanks for pointing out my error; I'll significantly edit that paragraph.  It is relevant for other missiles, but not the AGM-129. Thanks again.

Perfect, glad I could help

There is one pertinent line from this answer.  The missile is not intended to land.  Most vertical stabilizers  are upward to facilitate landing on a runway.  Even though the wings/stabilizer are retracted initially, it is highly doubtful they are designed to retract once launched.

@Gabe: there are many pictures and videos online where you can see how it works

@sophit thanks for suggesting a video search. Interestingly found this and looks like the vertical stabilizer is never folded, the wings definitely are though. I think @ AmazonDiesInDarkenss initial point is good and would make sense even though if the missile is launched from the B-52H, because I guess it would allow to be launched from other aircraft as well while reducing the complexity(and cost) of the missile by having one less part that needs to be folded.

The reason is to reduce radar detection from above.
Cruise missiles are designed to fly low, to avoid detection. Low altitudes make it harder to detect because the radar horizon is smaller, and things on the ground, like terrain and trees, get in the way of the signal.
The way you counter a low-flying vehicle is to detect it from above, via a radar on an aircraft.
Therefore, stealth features on the AGM-129 were designed to reduce the radar cross section from above, which resulted in features like the vertical stabilizer and air intake being placed on the bottom.
A similar layout is used on the Storm Shadow.

The bottom mounting also had the aerodynamic benefit of providing a favourable rolling moment to help the elevons when rolling into a bank.

Just adding to the above: "Not just the wings were backward, all the low observable features were oriented towards defeating detection from above, not below. This resulted in an upside-down-looking airframe of sorts. " https://www.twz.com/31286/the-saga-of-the-agm-129-cruise-missile-that-was-basically-a-stealth-jet-designed-upside-down

Here's a Dornier DO-335 Pfeil from WW2.

The vertical stabiliser hanging down also did dual duty to protect the rear pusher prop from damage.

Since your question is asking about vertical stabilisers generally and was not specific to the example missile, here's a historical reason why a rudder might hang down.

Good example, up voted.

A big reason missed, is that this would prevent deep stall of your vertical stabilizer. Where the vertical stabilizer loses its functionality because of the turbulent air from a stalled main wing.
Typically we consider stall in a high angle of attack situation (the reverse, stall happening at a high negative angel of attack is mostly indication of other major problems).
With high angle of attack the tail is "lower" than the main wing, so a vertical stabilizer high up on the tail would be more likely to be in the disturbed air flow of the main wing.
